# Display Firebase data previously/currently submitted

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm simply trying to make a page where I have an input for a user's name and age, then they submit that, and it sends that to the Firebase database, and that is working perfectly. The other thing I'm trying to do is display the data submitted in a "view" section. So just display the user's name and age below. I'm struggling to understand/get why my code is not working -- I have an h3 in place that should be replaced by the data that is stored in my database. 
Here is my code for the retrieval section
'Age' is what one category of children is called (the other is 'Name')

```
    <h2> View</h2>
<h3 id="showData"> Hello</h3>
<script>
  showData =  document.getElementByID('showData');
  var firebaseDataRef = firebase.database().ref().child('Age');
  firebaseDataRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
    showData.innerText = snapshot.value;
  });

the rest of my code:
    <input type=text" id="userName">
<input type="number" id="userAge">
<button id="btUpdateMessage" margin-bottom="20px" onclick="addFB()"> Update</button>
&nbsp;
<script>

  var lblCurrentMessage = document.getElementById('lblCurrentMessage'),
          userName = document.getElementById('userName'),
          btUpdateMessage = document.getElementById('btUpdateMessage'),
          userAge = document.getElementById('userAge'),
          rootRef = new Firebase('https://addview-c21e6.firebaseio.com'),
          currentMessageRef = rootRef.child('Name'),
          currentNameRef = rootRef.child('Age');
    function addFB()
  {
      currentMessageRef.push(userName.value);
      currentNameRef.push(userAge.value);
      userName.value = '';
      userAge.value = '';
    }
```

Comment: Update: I got the data to save to firebase perfectly, but am still struggling to get it to retrieve. I finally got something back, but it is telling me the object is undefined (it just shows undefined in the view section. Here is my updated code.

Answer (score 1):

`.value` is not a property of `DataSnapshot`. You need to call the `.val()` method on it.

```
firebaseDataRef.on('value', function(snapshot){
  showData.innerText = snapshot.val();
});
```

docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#val

Comment: Appreciate the help. It is still not working though. Could it be that I'm screwing up the references? I.E. should I be making a reference to a specific child? In my actual database when I click submit, it creates separate reference for a name and age so they are under two different children.

Comment: Quick update. I just realized it was because getElementByID was capitalized (the ID), but when I put 'Age' or name as the child it just returns object Object. I've seen this before but do not quite understand it. Again, my goal is also to be able to submit a name and an age and for it to show up below in real time -- am I close to that?

Comment: console.log() out the value of `snapshot.val()` and see what your object looks like. you probably are getting some nested object that you'll need to select. eg. `snapshot.val().ageProp` or something